# How to inject fluid into a mould?

Tags: fluid-simulation

This is the mould I made by designing the required component in CATIA, converting it into .stl format and importing it into blender and boolean operations on cuboid.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvBEM.jpg)

I assumed that regular fluid simulation would work in this case and would send fluid into the mould. But here the fluid is not behaving the way it's supposed to. Please help!

[image]

I have attached the file. Overwhelmed by such quick response. 
Thank you.

Comment: please add your .blend file to your question.  Grab the URL of the question
Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/
Select the blend file
Add the url of the question
Grab the url that results
Go back to the question and edit it

Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. I have attached the files. I have designed the keychain pattern in catia which i wanted to simulate injection moulding of =.. it would be really helpful if this gets done soon.